# Non Admins Getting Cached Posts

Tags: cache, apache

I'm having a strange issue with wordpress posts getting cached. If an admin is logged in they do not receive a cached post however a regular visit is cached. I do not have any caching plugins and the only way I can get the post to get updated is to restart apache2.

I do have cloudflare running but it's only caching images and js.

I feel like it has something to do with apache since restarting gets the pages to update but I can't figure out what I should be looking at.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Does this only happen with WordPress or other PHP scripts as well? Are you sure your apache or PHP-FPM aren't caching?

Comment: I can't say for sure if my apache or php-fpm isn't caching, need to look into that. I haven't tried just a regular php script but i'll write one up and see what happens.